# How to pass data to and from a bpopup jquery window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, bpopup

I am very new to using jQuery and javascript with website programming so this might be a very simple question. I implemented bpopup windows into my webpages and they work great so far. My questions is how do I send data to and from a bpopup window at will though. Below is my code for calling it with javascript.

```
function editPopupButton(){
    $('edit').bPopup({modalColor: 'grey'});
}
```

This is the view that the javascript shows

```
<div id="edit" style="display: none;">
  <span class="button b-close"><span>x</span></span>

     #Renders view here using ruby on rails code

</div>
```

and finally, here is the element that calls the javascript to make this all happen.

```
<button> onclick="editPopupButton()"> Edit </button>
```

So since I am new to all of this, I am not sure how to provide data to be sent to the popup window/the view being rendered. My first guess would be put it in the call to the javascript editPopupButton(); function as a parameter, but once in the method, I don't understand how to make it available from the view as data. If it makes a major difference in how it could be done, I am making the website in Ruby On Rails.

Any help and explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: One thing that has saved me in dealing with javascript is the [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem. It's specifically written to help pass code into a javascript function on a ERB view page. However I'm not familiar with bPopup so I'm afraid that's as much help as I can provide.